# convert to and from uncompressed bitmap to byte array

Tags: android, image, bitmap, byte

I am trying to implement two methods.

One that takes an ImageView as input and outputs uncompressed byte array.

The second takes byte array input and converts to a bitmap.

These are the two methods I use however bytesToImage() fails to produce a valid bitmap representation of the output of imageToBytes:

```
    private static byte[] imageToBytes(ImageView iv) {


        byte[] imageInByte = null;
        Bitmap originalImage;

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();

        originalImage = drawable.getBitmap();

        int numOfbytes = originalImage.getByteCount();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(numOfbytes);
        originalImage.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
        imageInByte = buffer.array();

        return imageInByte;
}



 private static Bitmap bytesToImage(byte data[]) {


        ByteBuffer byte_buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

        byte_buffer.rewind();

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(60, 60, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byte_buffer);

        return bmp;

}
```

These methods are then called in the following way:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewInput);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.panda);


imageInBytes = imageToBytes(iv);

Bitmap bmp = bytesToImage(imageInBytes);

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewOutput);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

However the imageViewOutput just displays an empty whitebox.

The image panda is a .bmp image

Comment: `originalImage = drawable.getBitmap();`. After that statemsnt assign originalImage to your image view. Does it become blank?

Comment: No - that displays the original image correctly

Comment: After createBitmap() do a copyPixelsToBuffer(new_buffer(). Compare the amount of bytes you get in new_buffer with the amount of bytes in byte_buffer.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my byteToImage() method as imageToBytes() successfully returns a byte array

Comment: imageToBytes returns byte array of length 4233600

Comment: If I then turn this byte array back into a byte buffer then indeed I get the same data length so it seems that byte_buffer is being created succesfully. The problem is then probably with

bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byte_buffer);

Comment: So the byte_buffer in bytesToImage() seems to contain the correct byte information but when bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byte_buffer) is called then the result bitmap when displayed is just a white box.

Comment: You did not `Compare..`. Why not? I asked you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the problem is with the bitmap in bytesToImage being incorrectly configured.

This requires the original bitmap to be passed in directly.

Here is the updated bytesToImage method which gives correct answer.

```
private static Bitmap bytesToImage(byte data[], Bitmap originalImage) {

    Bitmap newBmp;
    newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getConfig());


    ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

    buffer1.rewind();
    newBmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer1);

    byte[] imageInByte = null;



    ByteBuffer byte_buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);



    byte_buffer.rewind();



    newBmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byte_buffer);


    return newBmp;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a sick function. Why would you need twice a copyPixelsFromBuffer()? Dont give it a complete Bitmap as parameter but only the three properties of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on your imageToBytes method

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

And on your bytesToImage

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I don't want to compress the image format - I need to be able to convert to and from raw bitmap, uncompressed data